# I need return datas from google maps to my activity

Tags: java, android

I need a recommendation for realised this function.
For example, I pressed on button and started Google maps, after selecting the desired location, Google maps returned this geodata: "37.781157,-122.398720" to my application. How is realised this functional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like this ....change it according to your requirement

```
map.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLongClick(LatLng point) {
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("Custom location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));enter code here
            }
        });
```

in the above code the LatLng point contains the co-ordinates on the long pressed..